# How do I merge two objects blending topology so a bevel can be applied on merging edges

Tags: mesh, topology

How do I merge two objects blending topology so a bevel can be applied on merging edges?
See example image.
I have viewed so many tutorials but they all skip over linking the two topologies!

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hello, maybe work with a sphere that has less faces? Do you have an image of your reference object?

Comment: @moonboots Not sure what you mean by reference object?
The two images are in my original post, the sphere and the square pointy wedge.
I can make a sphere with less faces and subdivide it later I guess, but how to merge them?
CTRL J does not merge the topologies

Comment: actually instead of merging you could simply extrude the faces of your sphere and give it the shape of your other object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of merging the two shapes you could mirror, extrude some faces of your sphere and flatten them on the axis:

[image]

Switch to top view and use the *Shear* operation to tilt the extrusion (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd>):

[image]

Bevel the joint:

[image]